# Unable to mock express controller in Vitest

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, vitest

I'm trying to test that a call to a certain backend route eventually hits the correct controller function in an express app.

I'm attempting to do this using Vitest & supertest - but I'm struggling to mock the controller function.

```
**metafieldsControllers.js**

// @route     POST /metafields/save
// @desc      Saves a new value for an app-owned metafield

export const appMetafieldSave = async (req, res, next) => {
  <!-- stuff here -->
  res.status(201).json({ message: "Save successful!", savedValue });
}

// @route     GET /metafields/:namespace/:key
// @desc      Gets an app owned metafield by namespace and key

export const appMetafieldRetrieve = async (req, res, next) => {
  <!-- stuff here -->
  res.status(200).json(appInstallationData.metafield);
}
```

Things I have tried that haven't worked in my Vitest test file are...

```
***controllers.test.js***

import request from "supertest";
import { describe, expect, test, vi } from "vitest";

import { serve } from "../../../server/__tests__/serve";
import * as metafieldsControllers from "../metafieldsControllers.js";

describe("metafieldsControllers", async () => {
  const { app } = await serve(process.cwd(), false);

  // Mock verify-request
  vi.mock(`${process.cwd()}/server/middleware/verify-request.js`, () => ({
    default: vi.fn(() => (req, res, next) => {
      next();
    }),
  }));

  // Mock appMetafieldSave
  const controllerSpy = vi.spyOn(metafieldsControllers, "appMetafieldSave");

  controllerSpy.mockImplementation(() => {
    console.log("I'm running");
  });

  test("Call to metafields/save route hits the controller", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).post("/metafields/save");
    console.log("response", response);
    expect(controllerSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

^ This fails with AssertionError: expected "appMetafieldSave" to be called 1 times. Logging out the response shows that the request hit the original un-mocked controller.

```
***controllers.test.js***

import request from "supertest";
import { describe, expect, test, vi } from "vitest";

import { serve } from "../../../server/__tests__/serve";

describe("metafieldsControllers", async () => {
  const { app } = await serve(process.cwd(), false);

  // Mock verify-request
  vi.mock(`${process.cwd()}/server/middleware/verify-request.js`, () => ({
    default: vi.fn(() => (req, res, next) => {
      next();
    }),
  }));

  // Mock appMetafieldSave
  vi.mock(
    `${process.cwd()}/server/controllers/metafieldsControllers.js`,
    () => {
      return {
        appMetafieldSave: vi.fn(() => (req, res, next) => {
          res.status(201);
        }),
        appMetafieldRetrieve: vi.fn(() => (req, res, next) => {
          res.status(200);
        }),
      };
    }
  );

  test("Call to metafields/save route hits the controller", async () => {
    const response = await request(app).post("/metafields/save");
    console.log("response", response);
    expect(response.status).toEqual(201);
  });
});
```

^ This fails with a timeout.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?